# Using a linear equation to create a radially interpolated circle

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, raster

Given a linear equation, I want to use the slope to create a circle of values around a given point, defined by the slope of the linear equation if possible

Im currently a bit far away - can only make the radial plot but do not know how to connect this with an input equation. My first thought would be to change the opacity using import matplotlib.animation as animation and looping matplotlib's alpha argument to become gradually more and more opaque. However the alpha doesnt seem to change opacity.

Code:

```
# lenth of radius
distance = 200

# create radius 
radialVals = np.linspace(0,distance)

# 2 pi radians = full circle
azm = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
r, th = np.meshgrid(radialVals, azm)
z = (r ** 2.0) / 4.0

# creates circle
plt.subplot(projection="polar")

# add color gradient
plt.pcolormesh(th, r, z)

plt.plot(azm, r,alpha=1, ls='', drawstyle = 'steps') 

#gridlines
# plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to solve it, the idea is to create a mesh, calculate the colors with a function then use `imshow` to visualize the mesh.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np


def create_mesh(slope,center,radius,t_x,t_y,ax,xlim,ylim):
    """
    slope: the slope of the linear function
    center: the center of the circle
    raadius: the radius of the circle 
    t_x: the number of grids in x direction 
    t_y: the number of grids in y direction 
    ax: the canvas 
    xlim,ylim: the lims of the ax
    """
    def cart2pol(x,y):
        rho = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        phi = np.arctan2(y,x)
        return rho,phi
    
    def linear_func(slope):
        # initialize a patch and grids  
        patch = np.empty((t_x,t_y))
        patch[:,:] = np.nan
        x = np.linspace(xlim[0],xlim[1],t_x)
        y = np.linspace(ylim[0],ylim[1],t_y)
        x_grid,y_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        
        # centered grid
        xc = np.linspace(xlim[0]-center[0],xlim[1]-center[0],t_x)
        yc = np.linspace(ylim[0]-center[1],ylim[1]-center[1],t_y)
        xc_grid,yc_grid = np.meshgrid(xc, yc)
        rho,phi = cart2pol(xc_grid,yc_grid)
        linear_values = slope * rho
        
        # threshold controls the size of the gaussian 
        circle_mask = (x_grid-center[0])**2 + (y_grid-center[1])**2 < radius
        patch[circle_mask] = linear_values[circle_mask]
    
        return patch

    # modify the patch
    patch = linear_func(slope)
    extent = xlim[0],xlim[1],ylim[0],ylim[1]
    ax.imshow(patch,alpha=.6,interpolation='bilinear',extent=extent,
              cmap=plt.cm.YlGn,vmin=v_min,vmax=v_max)
        
        
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(12,6))
slopes = [40,30]
centroids = [[2,2],[4,3]]
radii = [1,4]

for item in ax:item.set_xlim(0,8);item.set_ylim(0,8)
v_max,v_min = max(slopes),0

create_mesh(slopes[0],centroids[0],radii[0],t_x=300,t_y=300,ax=ax[0],xlim=(0,8),ylim=(0,8))
create_mesh(slopes[1],centroids[1],radii[1],t_x=300,t_y=300,ax=ax[1],xlim=(0,8),ylim=(0,8))

plt.show()
```

The output of this code is

[image: output]

As you can see, the color gradient of the figure on the left is not as sharp as the figure on the right because of the different slopes (`[40,30]`).

Also note that, these two lines of code

```
v_max,v_min = max(slopes),0

ax.imshow(patch,alpha=.6,interpolation='bilinear',extent=extent,
          cmap=plt.cm.YlGn,vmin=v_min,vmax=v_max)
```

are added in order to let the two subplots share the same colormap.

Comment: Great thank you! I had two quick questions - how would you change the radius size and the position of the centroid?

Comment: @Evan you're welcome, that's simple, check out my updated post.

Comment: thanks again @meTchaikovsky. and I assume that the updated patch contains the values of the meshgrid?

Comment: @Evan you're welcome :) The patch is the meshgrid, as you can see in `create_mesh`, the function `linear_func` creates the mesh, and then the mesh, i.e., the patch, is visualized by `ax.imshow`.

Comment: how could I add y-intercepts in addition to the slopes?

Comment: @Evan Maybe change this `linear_values = slope * rho` to `linear_values = slope * rho + b`?